# pgp encryption with php "decryption failed"

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt files with php. The files should be asynchronously decrypted with pgp.

When I used the default gnupg-php-functions the encryption works well. I can decipher it on console. If I try to decipher it with php I always get an unspecific Exception: "decryption failed"

I've tried it also with different Keys. I also used an other library "singpolyma/openpgp-php".

Where could be the problem?

```
$sMessage = 'Huhu';
$recipient = 'test@email.com';
$sPassword = '1234';

// initialize PGP
putenv("GNUPGHOME=".__DIR__."/.pgp/");
$oPgp = new gnupg();
$oPgp->import($sPublicKey);
$oPgp->seterrormode(GNUPG_ERROR_EXCEPTION);
$oPgp->import($sPublicKey);
$oPgp->addencryptkey($recipient);

$ciphertext = $oPgp->encrypt($sMessage);
echo '<pre>'.$ciphertext.'</pre>';
file_put_contents('/tmp/ciphertext.gpg', $ciphertext);

// create new GnuPG object
$gpg = new gnupg();
$gpg->import($sPrivateKey);

// throw exception if error occurs
$gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION);

// ciphertext message
$gpg->adddecryptkey($recipient, $sPassword);
$plaintext = $gpg->decrypt($ciphertext);
echo '<pre>' . $plaintext . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Problem. It is caused by the changes in gnupg v2. Problem was the use of a key-password. It could be solved by configuring pgp for unattended password use. Have a look at "yougot@haxed.com"'s comment at [phpt.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-decrypt.php).

Comment: Yeah? How do you do that in PHP??

Comment: Edit the config as in the linked article. I&#39;ll post a code sample tomorrow https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Unattended_passphrase

Comment: I found an actual php solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970228/gnupg-decrypt-command-with-php-with-passphrase that allows to decrypt using passphrase and another user's key files